# Programs take a long time (2 minutes) to start in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, itunes, microsoft-excel-2013

Sometimes when launching programs like excel or itunes on my Windows 10 desktop they take a long time to start or show the window.

If I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and open the Task Manager I can see that the program is running but I don't see a window and there is no icon on my task bar or icon tray.

What can I do to try to solve this issue?

Comment: This could be a memory issue.  If you are running low on memory, then memory in use by other applications gets swapped to disk to make room for the new app.  How much memory do you have?

Comment: Like Paul said: it could be a memory issue - but it could also be a dying hard drive. have you considered checking your hard drive health ?

Comment: I have 8GB of memory. I have not checked my hard drives health